# How to talk to new company HR about my notice period

Tags: job-search, human-resources, job-change, resignation, notice-period

I am in mess regarding my 2 months of notice period in my current company. I am looking for change and I don't want to resign before getting new job.

After applying on new jobs when I get call of HR, they ask about my notice period, I am telling them my notice period is of **2 months**. Then they are asking is it negotiable I am telling  I am not sure need to talk with them.

After that HR not calling me back than to schedule interview.

What should I do now is there any way to get offer letter without resigning?

Comment: Apply to better companies. If two months notice is standard (in your country and for your role) then a company not willing to wait is a huge no-no and a big insight about their culture. Something you should NOT ignore.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Thank you for your input.

Comment: "Then they are asking is it negotiable I am telling I am not sure need to talk with them."  Never do that. Just clearly say "No, it's not negotiable."  You must keep things SUPER SIMPLE in talks with a new employer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Adriano's comment, not to be worried about the company much which is not willing to provide you support even before your joining.

Two months of notice period is reasonable (assuming you're in India) and common, there is no reason for not to understand the liabilities and legalities of serving the notice period.

Keep looking, you'll be getting other offers from other organizations who would likely to be waiting for  you to complete your notice period and then get you on-boarded.

By the way,

> *I am looking for change and I don't want to resign before getting new job.*

is usually the best practice, never hand out your resignation until you get another confirmed offer, unless you are OK with losing out your paycheck.

Comment: Thank you Sourav for answer. It is helpful.

Comment: Arvind raja Welcome to worst workplace in the world named "India" :) sorry but I hate everything about working in India.